# Grep lines from a file in batches according to a format

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with contents as:

> Hi 
>  welcome 
> ! Chunk Start 
>  Line 1
> Line2
> ! Chunk Start
>  Line 1 
>  Line 2 
>  Line 3 
> ! Chunk Start
>  Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
> Line 4
> Line 5
> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
> Line 4

Now, everything beginning with **"! Chunk Start"**  and before the next **"! Chunk Start"**  is a chunk, i.e. the lines between **"! Chunk Start"** , make a chunk. I need to get the contents of each chunk in a single line. i.e.:

> Line 1 Line 2
> Line 1 Line2 Line 3
> Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4 Line 5 Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4

I have done this, but I think there should be a better way. The way I have done this is:

`grep -A100 "! Chunk Start" file.txt`

Rest of the logic is there to concat the lines. But this **A100** is what I am worried about. What if there are more than 100 lines in a chunk, this will fail.
I probably need to do this with awk/sed. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/^! Chunk Start/d;:a;$!N;/! Chunk Start/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;d' file
```

Delete upto and including the first line containing `! Chunk Start`. Gather up lines replacing the newline by a space. When the next match is found print the first line, delete the pattern space and repeat.

Comment: This is working fine for me. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the command.

Comment: This may be cleaner than my `gawk` version.  There also seems to be [no limit on the line length](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html) in GNU `sed`.  I'm not sure about the portability of this particular `sed` command, but `gawk` is usually something I have to install manually as it doesn't come with all distributions.  On the other hand, you can expect some kind of `sed` to be pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @e0k You can expect some kind of `awk` to be everywhere too and not all seds are GNU sed, just like not all awks are GNU awk.

Answer (score 5):

You can use GNU AWK (`gawk`).  It has a GNU extension for a [powerful regexp form of the record separator `RS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) to divide the input by `! Chunk Start`.  Each line of your "chunks" can then be processed as a field.  Standard AWK has a limit on the number of fields (99 or something?), but  [`gawk` supports up to `MAX_LONG` fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Implementation-Limitations.html).  This large number of fields should solve your worry about 100+ input lines per chunk.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="! Chunk Start\n";FS="\n"}NR>1{$1=$1;print}' infile.txt
```

AWK (and GNU AWK) works by dividing input into *records*, then dividing each record into *fields*.  Here, we are dividing records (record separator `RS`) based on the string `! Chunk Start` and then dividing each record into fields (field separator `FS`) based on a newline `\n`.  You can also specify a custom *output* record separator `ORS` and custom *output* field separator `OFS`, but in this case what we want happen to be the defaults (`ORS="\n"` and `OFS=" "`).

When dividing into records, the part before the first `! Chunk Start` will be considered a record.  We ignore this using `NR>1`.  I have interpreted your problem specification

> everything beginning with "! Chunk Start" and before the next "! Chunk Start" is a chunk

to mean that once `! Chunk Start` has been seen, everything else until the end of input belongs in *at least some chunk*.

The mysterious `$1=$1` forces `gawk` to reprocess the input line `$0`, which parses it using the input format (`FS`), consuming the newlines.  The `print` prints this reprocessed line using the output format (`OFS` and `ORS`).

**Edit:** The version above prints spaces at the end of each line.  Thanks to @EdMorton for pointing out that the default field separator `FS` separates on *whitespace* (including newlines), so `FS` should be left unmodified:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="! Chunk Start\n"}NR>1{$1=$1;print}' infile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and a very good explanation. The solution is working well.

Comment: This version leaves spaces at the end of the lines.  (I was hoping either it wouldn't make a difference or no one would notice.)  It's an easy thing to fix, but the `sed` answer by @potong filters this out already and is probably the more elegant and efficient solution.

Comment: You were definitely on the right track. If you hadn't changed the `FS` from it's default value (which matches all chains of white space, including newlines) you wouldn't have created those end of line spaces. I think nawk or maybe just old, broken awk, has a limit on number of fields but that's not a concern for standard (POSIX) awks.

Answer (score 3):

Good grief. Just use awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='! Chunk Start' '{$1=$1}NR>1' file
Line 1 Line2
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4 Line 5 Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Comment: ["In anything at all, perfection is finally attained not when there is no longer anything to add, but when there is no longer anything to take away, when a body has been stripped down to its nakedness."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/where-does-this-translation-of-saint-exuperys-quote-on-design-come-from).  AWK is best at this.

Comment: Careful - that might imply that brevity is desirable in itself but it's not, conciseness (brevity with clarity) is what's desirable in software :-).